# PHP: Upload de arquivos funciona para imagens mas não funciona para arquivos PDF

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Estou com um problema estranho: meu formulário funciona para upload de imagens mas não funciona para o upload de arquivos PDF.

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
$titulo             = $_POST['txtTitulo'];
$descricao      = $_POST['txtDescricao'];

$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['flFile']['name']);
$extension = ".".$extension['extension'];
$extension != '.';
$file = md5(time().rand()).$extension;
$anexo = 'assets/uploads/'.$file;
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['flFile']['tmp_name'], $anexo );

$query = "insert into tb_arquivos (id_arquivo, titulo, descricao, anexo)
values (null, '".$titulo."', '".$descricao."', '".$anexo."')";

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Se eu insiro uma imagem, tudo funciona perfeitamente. Mas, se eu insiro um PDF, eu perco todos os valores do formulário (inclusive os da variáveis $titulo e $descricao.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que o problema se encontrava no limite para upload de arquivos.

Como as imagens que eu costumo subir para o site são menores que 2MB, o problema nunca ocorria.

Para resolver este problema eu criei um arquivo .htaccess na raiz do projeto com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1G
php_value post_max_size 1G
```